# How to show comments in certain post in csv file in facebook scraper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, web-scraping, sentiment-analysis

hi i recently doing some facebook scraper that shows comments of the certain post but i have a problem in coding. How to show the date of the comments in .csv? hope someone answer thankyou in advance
[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCogP.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Just be aware that Facebook does not allow you to scrape them so don't be surprised if you get banned or your scraping stops working.